# Culture changing from 12 hr time format to 24 hour

Tags: vb.net, iis, cultureinfo, windows-server-2019

At the beginning of June we have been seeing odd things happening with the times we've been saving. With what seems like 0 updates to our servers, or code, many of our applications have been randomly saving a 24 hr time format instead of a 12 hr format. First thing in my mind was to check the culture.  So we added

```vb
Dim saveUtcNow As String
saveUtcNow = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("T", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
data.SetValue(String.Format("SIG_T_{0}", "PI"), saveUtcNow)
```

In theory this should always force a 12 hr format. But for some reason, that has made no change. We are still seeing random times in 24 hr format.

We have not been able to identify a solution, or even a cause of this formatting change. Can anyone thing of other ways besides browser language that would even cause something like this when calling a function on the server?

Comment: Yes, it was originally like that, but that format can be changed without forcing the culture.

Comment: Start logging `DateTimeFormatInfo.LongTimePattern` alongside the culture's name?

Comment: No controls.  Literally setting the time using the small function above.  The same code stopped working on June 3rd.  It's very strange.  I've seen this with dates, but forcing the culture always worked.  I don't get why time would be so different.  In my mind I would think either a browser update, or windows server patch.

Comment: Also, the 24 or 12 hour format doesn't happen all the time.  Some apps save the date as 12 hr format, some as 24 hr format.  That's what's so frustrating.  I cannot recreate the 24 hr format locally.  Works correcting saving the 12 hr format

Comment: Invariant Language for the "UI Culture", and False to "Enable Client Based Culture"

Comment: Slight different approach.  Assuming there is a DateTime type available in your storage If you didn't store date time data as strings, 24hr/12hr thing isn't a problem

Comment: True, but unfortunately, the data is stored in a SQL DB as an nvarchar(MAX).  Been this way for 20 years, never had an issue until beginning of June.

Comment: Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Yes, it happens in Chrome, IE, Safari, mobile versions and desktop.  And only sometimes.

Comment: Does anyone think it has nothing to do with the browser?  I've been going down that path because it's the only thing that makes sense to me.  But at this point, my judgement could be clouded.  Thanks.

Comment: sometimes? you mean that this problem occurs sometimes, not always?

Comment: Correct.  A user can fill out an application, hit the same code, and it is saved in a 12 hr format.  Another user fills out the app, and the date is saved in a 24 hr format.  The same code has been in place for a year, and it always saved as 12 hr format.  But starting June 3rd, is where we started seeing 24 hr formats saved.  That's what made me think it has to be some sort of a browser update.  But, I can't find any info about recent updates.

Comment: Have you updated your system version?

Comment: No server patches were applied.

Comment: Are your users in the same area? some cultures don't accept 24 hour time, and others don't accept AM/PM.

Comment: No, they are not in the same area.  Could be from anywhere in the world.  Mostly US though.  But from a culture perspective, the time is being set in .NET, so, it's done on the server and not the client.  By forcing the culture when setting the date or time, it "should" override the client culture setting.

Comment: I knew a Jim Girard a while ago from Baytown TX. Any relationship?